# How can I calculate the time difference in seconds?

Tags: javascript

I use this code to calculate the time difference in seconds between two dates. But something seems to be wrong with my code, because the function returns true even if the difference between two different dates is less than 3 minutes.

Why is the difference 997801 ? Shouldn't it be much less?

How can I find out if the previous date is older than 3 minutes?

```
dateToCheck = "\"2020-04-19T09:37:00.000Z\""

function isOlderThanThreeMinutes(dateToCheck)
{
    log.info("Now: " + Date.now() + " PreviousDate: " + dateToCheck);
    var secondsdifference = Date.now() - dateToCheck; 
    log.info("Difference: " + datedifference); 
    return Date.now() - dateToCheck > 180; // 180 seconds = 3 minutes
}

log.info(valuesAsDate);
iscurrentdategreater = isOlderThanThreeMinutes(valuesAsDate);
log.info("greaterthanthreeminutes: " + iscurrentdategreater);
```

logs:

```
"\"2020-04-19T09:37:00.000Z\""

"Now: 1587290017801 PreviousDate: Sun Apr 19 2020 09:37:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"

"Difference: 997801"

"greaterthanthreeminutes: true"
```

Comment: It seems like youre comparing a date to a string (the string you pass in to your function is not a date).

Comment: Why the `"\"` ? You really want those double-quotes preserved?

Comment: `Date.now() - dateToCheck` is like saying `DateObject - SomeStringOfMine` and expecting it will work by magic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because it gives you the difference in milliseconds not in seconds.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Comment: Thanx, it works now. I changed my code to: return Date.now() - Number(dateToCheck) > 180 * 1000;